# Run Hydro package on ROS indigo

Tags: ros, package, ros-hydro, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a Baxter robot that has an Oculus Hydra razor setup on it.  I also have a Clearpath Ridgeback that I am going to mount it on.  Both robots support running on Indigo so i upgraded the laptop.  My issue now is the package that runs the Hydra razor is only available for Hydro.  Is there any way to run a Hydro package with Ubuntu 14.04 and ROS Indigo.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269535/run-hydro-package-on-ros-indigo/) by [mewescott](https://answers.ros.org/users/31649/mewescott/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-08-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can run Hydro code in Indigo by cloning the repository to an Ubuntu 14.04 based system that also has ROS Indigo sourced. You can then make a catkin_workspace and put the code in that workspace to build it. If it builds, great. If not, you'll have to fight with it until it builds. Once it builds however, you will be able to use it alongisde your existing ROS system as long as you have that workspace sourced in whatever terminal you're using it with. I suggest adding it to your ~/.bashrc if it will be a continuing occurrence.

---

Originally posted by [DevonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/4255/devonw/) with karma: 644 on 2017-08-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mewescott](https://answers.ros.org/users/31649/mewescott/) on 2017-08-28**:
I don't know if I can get it to work but I will give it a try when I get to this stage.  I plan to install the Hydro distro code and the newer drivers on top of it.

**Comment by [mewescott](https://answers.ros.org/users/31649/mewescott/) on 2017-09-11**:
I have installed all the latest drivers and the Hydro version software written for the Baxter to Hydra interface.  It would not run.  I get the following messages and I am not sure how to correct them;
couldn't open hydra on /dev/hydra
couldn't open hidraw device
Any suggestions would be appreciated